# WPF - Create solid layout without designer

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, autolayout, accessibility

I'm blind and would like to use WPF as it is more accessible in many ways. However, the designer used to position elements onscreen isn't accessible.

In Winforms, I used the size and location attributes of each control to arange them in a way they didn't overlap onscreen. This had to do with logic, not sight, so it went fairly well.

In WPF, things are a bit different, though. I know there are several layout containers like Dockpanel, Stackpanel etc. However I am uncertain whether they would keep the controls from overlapping.

So my question is: If you couldn't see, how would you arrange controls to make sure they don't overlap? Which layout controls would you use?

Comment: Bravo dude! Although it's tough to answer this definitively, but I can recommend a couple things. For instance if you stick to panels like Grid with rows and columns and avoid elements like Canvas with hard set margins or transforms for your layout base, that should keep you pretty predictable. However either way this is a really fascinating question!

Comment: I'd need to add the controls to a certain (set) of columns and rows specifically to keep them from overlapping, right? Or does the system do that automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to place controls in WPF without overlapping them is to use `<Grid.RowDefinitions>`and `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`. 
You can either define your width and heights with fixed or relative values (using '*'). 
For good and simple explanation I can suggest these two sites:

- https://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html
- https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

Within the grid you can place again other controls, panels or even other grids with their own row and column definition, allowing for creative designs.

Comment: Excellent! the articles you posted gave me some ideas on what to do. Now once again this is more logic than sight related. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they would keep the controls from overlapping. This is actually an advantage of WPF: its containers place the controls relative to each other and other controls so they do not overlap and resize or move on window resizing. If the control size will exceed the size of the container, the part of the control will be hidden, not overlapping over it's neighbours. That relates to any container, except for canvas, where the elements are placed by absolute coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, too. I'll see whether I can achieve solid layouts now :)